# Porque al sacar una list con el fiter se cambia la list padre tambien angular

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando el filter para sacar una nueva list, pero el problema que tengo es que al modificar la list hija tambien afecta a la list padre que puedo hacer
El codigo es

```
this.listDatosVisitasFiler = this.listDatosVisitas.filter((c: { seC_VISCOM: number; }) => c.seC_VISCOM == idSec);
```

Comment: Prueba con `this.listDatosVisitasFilter = this.listDatosVisitas.filter((c: { seC_VISCOM: number; }) => c.seC_VISCOM == idSec).slice();`